# Google App Engine ASP.NET Core Web API + SignalR

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-signalr

I build an API with ASP.NET Core which is hosted in Google Cloud Platform. 
The backend additionally subscribes to Google's Pubsub topics and broadcasts messages using SignalR (1.0.0-alpha2-final).

The problem with signalR communication.

When the app is started locally (IIS) - signalR works perfectly.

If the app is deployed to Google App Engine - I get a response "501. Not implemented". If the app is deployed to Google Kubernetes - get 404.

Google tells that currently websockets are supported only in Go/Python/Java hosted apps.

Is there a solution or workaround for the problem?

Comment: I'm going to guess that since SignalR is in a public Alpha (and that Damien Edwards has said that it's a very early alpha) that support just isn't there yet. Plus, as you said "Google tells that currently websockets are supported only in Go/Python/Java hosted apps". Perhaps you could write an applet in Go/Python/Java which can communicate with Google's pubsub stuff instead of using SignalR, since it's not supported by Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Then again, one of the first links which shows up when I Google search for "google cloud signalr core" is http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/broadcasting-message-from-asp-net-core-to-angular-client-using-signalr/ I've not read through it fully yet, but that could be a starting point for you.

Comment: The point is that ASP.NET Core SignalR works perfectly with test clients until it is not hosted in GAE.
After moving to Kubernetes, it seems to be more or less functional, but the connection can be established from 3-4 attempt, otherwise, I receive 404.